# Best modern method to run a script after receiving an ftp'd file

Tags: sh, inotify, vsftpd, incron

I just starting writing a new interface where I need to process a file after it has been ftp'd into my server. Is [incron](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Incron) better than [inotify](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/inotify-tools/) in the long run or should I choose something else? BTW, I am using vsftpd.

p.s. I have already looked at other articles at this site but most of them are over 5 years old. I'm looking for the best solution in 2022.

Comment: You want to use the related `inotifywait` to watch for new files in the download directory and then do whatever you need with the file.

Comment: I only asked because incron (and any events registered via incrontab) will survive a reboot. While there is much more written about inotify, event traps created this way need to be reregistered after every reboot (unless I am mistaken or someone has a work around)

Comment: No, you are thinking right. The `inotify` and `inotifywait` functions are closely related. I haven't made use of `incron`. Generally when I need to watch for changes, I will start the watch process during boot (if system-wide) or though the run control file if on a per-user basis. I've always used `inotifywait` for that purpose.

Comment: I just realized that I may need to switch from vsftpd to proftpd

Comment: Not sure what features proftpd provides that vsftpd doesn't. I've used vsftpd for more than a decade and haven't run into any shortcomings.

Comment: proftpd offers some interesting features via the optional mod_exec feature (provided you are not using chroot).